# Error in Pager of a Ajax View

Tags: 7, views, ajax, organic-groups, paging

I am getting the following error in Ajax Enabled View, which uses Load More Pager.

[image]

I am not sure if its, entirely because of OG, as the error doesn't appear in Views Preview but only in the actual view rendering in a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. Its a bug in the views which doesn't handle the nested views. More about this issue can be found in https://www.drupal.org/node/1016602

I had to override a javascript function in views to fix it. But since it was very use-case specific, I am not sharing the details of the same.